# Analyzing signatures for Landsat clasification with Sextante in QGIS

Tags: qgis, landsat, sextante

I am defining my training data for a Landsat classification. I am digitizing the polygons with the field data in QGIS and I want to analyze the signatures of the Landsat images to avoid errors.

In ERDAS I use the Signature editor, but I think I can do it with the Sextante toolbox in QGIS.

Does anyone know of an example of this on the web?